# 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de recibir los datos del usuario actual y me da este error en el logcat:
'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

```
 private void fetch() {



    mCurrent_user_id = auth.getUid();


    final DatabaseReference query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("Prueba");



    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Upload> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Upload>()
                    .setQuery(query.child(mCurrent_user_id), new SnapshotParser<Upload>() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Upload parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            return new Upload(snapshot.child("titulo").getValue().toString(),
                                snapshot.child("texto").getValue().toString());
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La excepción

```
'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Significa que tu objeto

```
snapshot.child("titulo").getValue().toString()
```

Esta en null, por ende no puedes pedirle el ToString() a un null

Puedes validar antes de tomar los datos que no sea null o utilizar un Try Catch y manejar excepciones

Comment: Como puedes ver Bruno agregue la imagen de la base de datos y si tengo "titulo" en la base de datos. @BrunoSosaFastTag

Comment: Usa el debug tu funcion query.child(mCurrent_user_id) no debe ser esa key de tu foto